# iPhone 4 screen resolution (code-wise)?

Tags: screen-resolution, iphone-4

I had an epiphany just now.
In some places in my very first iPhone app I have hardcoded values referring to the screen width and/or height (320, 460).

now I realize that i never noticed this because in the iPhone 4 simulator i dont notice any drawing issues.

So does this mean the iPhone 4 internally converts 320 to be whatever the width for its screen resolution? i doubt it. But then again, why would i be seeing everything appearing to be fine when i run?

Example:
If I make a ball draw at position (320, 100) I can clearly see that it is drawing at the far right edge of the screen.

What is going on here?

Comment: No it does not adapt the screen it's standard 320 for the iphone. It actually adapts the simulator to the screen makes it bigger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No it does not adapt the screen it's standard 320 for the iphone. It actually adapts the simulator to the mac screen makes it bigger.  And about the ball 320 is from left to right 0---320, and the 460 is from up to down  0----460. sow putting the ball at 320,100 should place it in the fa right.

Comment: i have seen my app running on an iPhone 4 (retina display). And there doesnt appear to be any draw/position issues. So the device must be doing something to correct this.

Comment: Are you sure your not putting the 320 in the height field(460)?

Comment: I dont see why this would make a difference. If i were putting the 320 in the 460 side, it'd be even more obvious (even on a non-retina display screen). So yes, im pretty sure im not making this mistake.